# Inject value of returned auth2 to angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-oauth

I have looked for a while and not found a solution to my problem, even though I think it might be very simple.

I use angularJS and authenticate with Google auth2, in order to retrieve the current logged in user. 
I want to add the name of the user to a angularJS variable, just to display it on the page (for now, anyway).

Here is my relevant html:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="(((cut out my client id here))">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<body ng-app="CalendarApp" >
  <div class="container" ng-controller="CalendarCtrl">
    <div class="header well" >
      <h1> Some heading </h1>
      <p id="welcometext"> Welcome, {{userName}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and the relevant js here:

```
var myApp = angular.module('CalendarApp', []);
myApp.controller('CalendarCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.userName = "tst";

gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    fetch_basic_profile: true,
    scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
  auth2.signIn().then(function() {
    var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    $("#welcometext").text("Welcome, " + profile.getName()); //this is my current workaround, but don't like it.
    $scope.userName = profile.getName();
    console.log($scope.userName); //this prints the correct name
  });
}); // gapi.load
```

As you can derive from my comments, the auth call works, and retrieves the data. I want to access it from the angular `$scope.userName`. But if I display it on the site, it only displays "tst", and ignores the `$scope.userName = profile.getName();` statement.

I'm pretty sure this might be just a dumb mistake on my part, but I have been spending so much time on it already.

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the `auth2.signIn()` promise to a `$q` service promise that is integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle, use `$q.when`:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    fetch_basic_profile: true,
    scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
  //auth2.signIn().then(function() {
  //USE $q.when to integrate with AngularJS digest cycle
  $q.when(auth2.signIn()).then(function() {
    var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    //$("#welcometext").text("Welcome, " + profile.getName()); //this is my current workaround, but don't like it.
    $scope.userName = profile.getName();
    console.log($scope.userName); //this prints the correct name
  });
}); // gapi.load
```

By converting the `gapi` promise to a `$q` service promise, the AngularJS framework will react to changes to $scope by the `.then` method.

From the Docs:

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

--[AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. If anyone else stumbles over this, just make sure to inject $q to the scope like so

Comment: myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($q){
       //$q is available here
    });

Comment: You need to inject both `$scope` and `$q` into the controller construction function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this:

```
$("#welcometext").text("Welcome, " + profile.getName()); //this is my current workaround, but don't like
```

All you need to do is this:

```
$scope.userName = profile.getName();
```

If removing jQuery still doesn't work,

write this:

```
$scope.userName = profile.getName();
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

Bharat.